# Questions on Java's I/O Classes

Tags: java, inheritance, java-io

I am reading up on this tutorial on networking (client/server) in java and I had a question about something I don't understand.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

I been seeing this often enough

```
BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

and

```
BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt"));
PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("characteroutput.txt"));
```

I know that constructor for the BufferReader is

```
BufferedReader(Reader in)
```

1) I also know since InputStreamReader is inherited by the Reader class, that you can pass it through the BufferedReader constructor. But my question is why do we need the InputStreamReader? Is it because the InputStreamReader can hold a inputstream (according to it's constructor in the API)

Edit: made mistake on my part, please ignore this

<del>2) Now for the next part, inputStream & outputStream (according to the API) are inherited from the Object class. How do those two classes can be allocated as BufferedReader and PrintWriter respectively. Is this because they both are inherited by the object class, or is their another reason? Because if this is the case, how would anyone know what you can allocated as class as if everything is suppose to be inherited by the Objects class.</del>

3) Last but not least, another question about the BufferedReader and PrintWriter here

```
BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt"));
PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("characteroutput.txt"));
```

why did those two classes, choose to pass through a reference of the FileReader and FileWriter classes?

I guess I want some more info on why these specific classes were chosen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't show what the type of inputStream and outputStream actually are. If they were really InputStream and OutputStream, no, that assignment would not work.

Comment: Your questions reveal a misunderstanding which you should clear up before thinking about inheritance problems: binary vs text in Java.

You may want to read [this](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1k-JM1yQUnOat7VtCe47yRu3_dMceReaAtppoW0Eyh-4/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: @pvg Your right I messed up that part, thank you

Comment: @fge some of it made sense, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) To construct `BufferedReader`, you need a `Reader` parameter. `System.in` is not a `Reader`. Each part of the Java IO puzzle does only one thing: `InputStreamReader` gets you a `Reader` from an `InputStream`, then `BufferedReader` buffers that `Reader`.

2) They can't, precisely because of #1. First you wrap the `InputStream` in a `Reader` or `Writer` wrapper, then you can do other stuff.

3) Because they are reading from / writing to a file, not a stream. (EDIT: and, as pvg mentioned in comments, `inputStream = new BufferedReader(...)` and `outputStream = new PrintWriter(...)` are extremely confusing variable names.)

---

Basically, it's like a manufacture. You have `System.in`, which is an `InputStream`. That means he is handing you plain bytes. You don't want plain bytes; you want to be given characters (i.e. bytes parsed by some character encoding, such as, e.g. UTF-8). But `InputStream` doesn't know how to do that.

Enter `InputStreamReader`. As every `Reader`, he knows how to give you characters. Specifically `InputStreamReader` knows how to get bytes from an `InputStream` and hand it off as characters. So you put him in line just in front of `System.in`, so you don't have to deal with him.

But you don't want to get each character one at a time. You want more. You want to be able to read a whole line at once! You want... a buffer! Enter `BufferedReader`: he's the guy who stands in front of another `Reader`, collects each character and hamsters it away till you ask for some of it.

To see exactly what is going on, you need to understand the critical distinction between byte-based IO and text-based IO, and study each class' constructor function to see exactly what kind of thing it wraps (although names are a good hint).

Comment: Why has been this answer downvoted? It's exact what OP asked for! Also, an upvote,+1.

Comment: Agreed. Good answer. +1 from me too.

Comment: @Amadan
This answer was great, I really appreciate it. I did read a small article about java I/O but I think you filled in the blanks. 

I think the only part I am still lost on is where is this info being saved too? You mentioned:

Bytes -> char -> buffered = System.in 
being passed into InputStream being passed into InputStreamReader being passed into BufferedReader.

So the stream ends up being raw then converted then buffered, but where is the data saved, is it saved to a private class variable? Because I know when you pass in a constructor, the object has to be saved to something, right?

Comment: Doesn't have to, but usually is. However, that's not really your problem any more, since those classes are from the standard library; you can just treat them as black boxes. All you need to know is that if you wrap something in `BufferedReader`, you suddenly are able to use `readLine`, for example. But yes, if you're curious, [somewhere deep down](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/BufferedReader.java), `BufferedReader` remembers which `Reader` he is getting his stuff from, and also has a notepad (or rather a `char[]`) to jot down what he said.

Comment: Thanks so much man, also that link you posted. THANK YOU. I been looking for something just like this!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, Here is simple reason

This is decorator design pattern.
You take a basic object and keep on adding required decorations on top of it.
Example: Pizza with 2 toppings ( i am hungry now)

You do this because it reduces the number of different classes needed (InputStreamReader * Buffered/UnBuffered * bla bla bla results in many different combinations so if we have one child class for each combination, it will be 100+ stream classes and we will be confused, so we simply decorates it ( all types have same interface and we pass each other in constructor)

If still in doubt just google decorator pattern for details